# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for .... in undefined

Tags: javascript

I have got a following code:

```
function sendAjax(myData){
  $.ajax({
      type: myData["verb"],
      url: "url" in myData["url"] ? myData["url"] : "/default123",
      //..............
```

If I don't pass "`url`" as a key then I'll get the error of "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'url' in undefined` ".

How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
url: myData["url"] || "/default123",
```

Comment: sure, but would not it be better to use "in" operator?

Comment: You could use `in` (and could argue for it over this answer for clarity's sake perhaps), but your usage of it in your question is going to get you that error if `myData['url']` doesn't exist (meaning it would be `undefined`). The other answers here so far tell you how to use `in` based on what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: @AlanDert this is less code and generally if that object property doesn't exist, then it will reliably resolve falsy.

Answer (score 2):

`url : "url" in myData ? myData["url"] : "/default123"`